# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup due to access control checks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, xmlhttprequest

I am using nodeJS and expressJS for backend and ReactJS for frontend of my application. Everything works fine when run locally on my computer. However, I recently have tried to deploy the app using Heroku. The app successfully launches at the given link from Heroku but then whenever I try to sign in/sign up I'm always thrown an error from the backend. The error is as follows when I am using Safari and Google Chrome respectively:

[image: Safari Console Error]

[image: Google Chrome Console Error]

I have already enabled cors on my expressJS server, what is the likely cause of the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your ReactJS code has the url `http://localhost:5000/` hard coded in it somewhere. If your same Heroku instance serves the ReactJS and provides your API endpoints, then you should consider using

```
 /api/users/signup
```

for the  URL of your API endpoint instead of

```
 http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup
```

This wrong URL shows up as an access control issue because browsers block external pages served by https to use localhost APIs.  Because cybercreeps.